# Transform XML files in a folder to XML files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Solved my own question after few trials and errors. Thanks to all for their help.

I have a question about how to transform a set of XML files located in a folder on the local system. I need to transform the files to XML while keeping the original names, which are based on the topic text().

I am currently able to transform the a file using the xslt and I get the desired result, but because I have a good number of files it is not practical to transform the files one at a time.

My input XML look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic>
   <title class="- topic/title ">
      Term
   </title>
   <body class="- topic/body ">
      <p class="- topic/p ">Paragraph new</p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">(See New parag.)</p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">(See Next parag.)</p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">(See Test.)</p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">(See The other parag)</p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">(Refer to the conclusion)</p>
   </body>
</topic>
```

and my XSLT is the following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" >    

    <!-- This adds DOCTYPE declaration -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" 
        doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" 
        name="mygloss"  doctype-system="glossary.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="no"  indent="yes" />
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="files" select="collection('../A/?select=*.dita;recurse=yes')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="$files//topic">
            <!--had issues with this portion, but fixed it by changing from topic/>text() to title/text(). -->
            <xsl:result-document href="outputDITANEW/{title/text()}.dita" format="mygloss"> 

                <glossentry id="{concat('test', generate-id())}">
                    <glossterm id="{concat('test_title', generate-id())}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </glossterm>
                    <glossdef>
                        <xsl:for-each select="body">
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </glossdef>
                </glossentry>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
<glossentry id="test_d2e11">
   <glossterm id="new_term_d2e3">
      Term
   </glossterm>
   <glossdef>
      <p>Paragraph new</p>
      <p>(See New parag.)</p>
      <p>(See Next parag.)</p>
      <p>(See Test.)</p>
      <p>(See The other parag)</p>
      <p>(Refer to the conclusion)</p>
   </glossdef>
</glossentry>
```

I have tried to use xslt collection() and result-document(), but I am unable to make it work.

The above xslt gives me this error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat().

Hopefully this will give more clarity to my question.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What problem are you facing when using  collection() and result-document()?

Comment: Using collection() and xsl:result-document is the right way. Tell us what you did and how it failed, and we can help to fix your mistakes.

Comment: I have updated my question and the problem that I am running into, which is the following error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat().

Comment: I have now made progress and the above error does not show up anymore and I get the resulting xml files when using the below line of code: <xsl:result-document href="outputDITANEW/{position()}.dita">. What I would really need  is to get the file name based on the topic text() from the input xml. I have tried a few ways without success, every time I get the following error: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI. Could you please look  into my XSLT and let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own question after few trials and errors. Thanks to all for their help.

Key change was made here:

```
<xsl:result-document href="outputDITANEW/{title/text()}.dita" format="mygloss">
```